# Duda asistente de voz Python

Tags: python

Como podría hacer para que este asistente de voz cuando no haya reconocido ninguna voz pueda volver a pedirle a la persona de que vuelva a hablar de nuevo después de que diga "No he podido reconocer su voz"?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import webbrowser 

sr.Microphone(device_index=1)

r = sr.Recognizer()

r.energy_threshold=20000

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

    print("Que desea buscar?")

    audio = r.listen(source)

    print("Reconociendo...")

    try:
        dest = r.recognize_google(audio)
        url = "https://www.google.com/search?q="

        search_url=url+dest

        webbrowser.open(search_url)
            
    except:
            print("No he podido reconocer su voz")
```

Comment: ponlo en un ciclo `while`

Answer (score 2):

Como dijo @Christian, pon esto en un bucle `while`:

```
while True:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        # resto del código
```

Buen ejemplo en documentación: [default-argument-values](https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values)